Material Design scroll-away searchbar with recyclerview
I would like my Material Design Searchbar to scroll-away/collapse when scrolling down in my recyclerview. I followed the guidelines from here but I can't get it to work.
My activity XML:


<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto">

    <com.google.android.material.appbar.AppBarLayout
        android:id="@+id/appBarLayout"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent">

        <com.google.android.material.appbar.MaterialToolbar
            android:id="@+id/topAppBar"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:minHeight="?attr/actionBarSize"
            app:title="Test"
            app:navigationIcon="@drawable/ic_navigate_back"/>

    </com.google.android.material.appbar.AppBarLayout>

    <fragment
        android:id="@+id/nav_host_fragment_activity_standalone"
        android:name="androidx.navigation.fragment.NavHostFragment"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        app:defaultNavHost="true"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@id/appBarLayout" />

</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>



My fragment XML:


<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.coordinatorlayout.widget.CoordinatorLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <!-- NestedScrollingChild goes here (NestedScrollView, RecyclerView, etc.). -->
    <androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView
        android:id="@+id/recUserlist"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_marginStart="16dp"
        android:layout_marginEnd="16dp"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior"
        app:layoutManager="androidx.recyclerview.widget.LinearLayoutManager" />

    <com.google.android.material.appbar.AppBarLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
        android:backgroundTint="@color/surface_900">
        <com.google.android.material.search.SearchBar
            android:id="@+id/search_bar"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:hint="Username" />
    </com.google.android.material.appbar.AppBarLayout>

    <com.google.android.material.search.SearchView
        android:id="@+id/searchview"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:hint="Username"
        app:layout_anchor="@id/search_bar">
        <androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView
            android:id="@+id/recFilteredUserlist"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:orientation="vertical"
            app:layoutManager="androidx.recyclerview.widget.LinearLayoutManager" />
    </com.google.android.material.search.SearchView>
</androidx.coordinatorlayout.widget.CoordinatorLayout>



The SearchBar does not scroll-away when scrolling down the recyclerview unless the recyclerview is nested inside a NestedScrollView.
However, I would like to avoid placing my recyclerview into a nestedscrollview because this causes performance issues: all recyclerview items will be bound/rendered at once.
What am I missing here?

The problem was solved by changing nestedscrollingenabled from false to true on the recyclerview.
